# How do I install the Hughes net status meter?

Tags: 11.04, installation, adobe-air

I'm trying to install [Hughes net status meter](http://services.hughesnet.com/service_tools/Status_Meter/) on Ubuntu 11.04. I need a proper installation method. I have already managed to get AdobeAirInstaller.bin downloaded and installed Adobe Air. I have downloaded the Hughesnet status meter, saved it to the default folder "documents", and clicked to install.

The installation screen comes up momentarily but then disappears without finishing the installation. I installed it before using a tip that I found using google search but I dont recall the site or link where I found it. I cant seem to find it again after multiple searches. Please help.

Comment: Still no luck finding the site I got the instructions from. I appreciate the edits but I would appreciate an answer even more, thanks.

Comment: Ok, I found my answer after an Adobe-air update, it was adobe-air that wasn't working correctly apparently.                                                                                                                         The upgrade screen popped up so I updated it then tried installing the Hughesnet status meter again and it installed perfectly.